# hash failed to decrypt on other programs

Tags: php

I am having problems using this code which I managed to get from somewhere on the internet to encrypt/decrypt data which I'll use to encode some documents via QR codes.
encrypt/decrypt works fine when I use this program.
but the problem is if I am using a valid AES 256 CBC the hashes should encrypted via this and can also be decrypted using online AES 256 CBC available on various websites using the right key and IV.
when I try the random online programs say the hash must be a multiplication of 16.
here is a sample hash in which I write my name"ZzNkMDA2VmRzQU5WU01tbFNQcE5YZz09"
here is the iv"42301-4279279-31"
and 256 bit key is "&E)H+MbQeThWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-JaNcRf"
and here is the code

```
function encrypt_decrypt($string, $action = 'encrypt')

{

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";

    $secret_key = '&E)H+MbQeThWmZq4t7w!z%C*F-JaNcRf'; // user define private key

    $secret_iv = '42301-4279279-31'; // user define secret key

    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16); // sha256 is hash_hmac_algo

    if ($action == 'encrypt') {

        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

        $output = base64_encode($output);

    

    } else if ($action == 'decrypt') {

        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

    }

    return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, you forgot  base64_encode($output).

```
 function decrypt($encrypted_string, $secretKey,$secretIv) {
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash('sha256', $secretKey);
        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secretIv), 0, 16);
        return  openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_string), 
             $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    
    
    function encrypt($string,$secretKey,$secretIv){
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash('sha256', $secretKey);
        $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secretIv), 0, 16);
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        return base64_encode($output);
    }
```